# mySql force item in front of siblings in nested set

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets

I have hierarchical data (categories) stored in a mySql database using the nested set model.

All is working perfectly only I now need the ability to add a property to any node (`force_to_top`) which will set the node to temporarily force to the top of its siblings, and I'm not 100% sure how to do this without physically changing the `lft` and `rgt` values.

When a nodes `force_to_top` property is turned on I don't want to store the original `lft` and `rgt` values elsewhere, change the `lft` and `rgt` values to move the node to the correct position, and then reset their original `lft` and `rgt` values once the `force_to_top` property is removed. I think that's going to cause massive problems further down the line, plus it seems like a very roundabout way of doing things? (correct me if that's in fact the simplest way! But I would like to find another, preferably only using sql not updating any values in the db)

I was wondering if it would be possible to somehow manipulate the output of the sql depending on the `force_to_top` property?

For example if we have the following structure

```
        Cars
        |
-----------------
|       |       |
Audi    Ford    VW
```

Which would have the following lft/rgt/force_to_top values:

```
node    lft    rgt  force_to_top
Cars    1      8    false
Audi    2      3    false
Ford    4      5    false
VW      6      7    false
```

When we output the child nodes of 'Cars', we'd be given:

```
Audi
Ford
VW
```

But lets say the node 'VW' has its `force_to_top` property set to `true`, what I would really need is the output of the child nodes of 'Cars' to now be:

```
VW
Audi
Ford
```

As I mentioned I've thought about storing the original `lft` and `rgt` values and resetting them after the `force_to_top` property is removed. The plus side of not doing it this way is the speed of turning off the `force_to_top` property, it would mean no data manipulation other than actually setting the `force_to_top` value to `false` again and the node would immediately drop back to its original position. And would also mean I don't need to create a storage area / extra tables / extra fields for the original `lft` and `rgt` values of each node.

I've also thought about doing this in the php after I've fetched the results, but for large data sets that could really slow things down.

I originally had to set the `force_to_top` nodes to the top of everything, which was very easy, simply `ORDER BY force_to_top, lft`, however now only forcing to the top of its siblings is a lot more complicated, as the node may be in the centre of a massive hierarchy.

Any suggestions or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles here with a similar problem (very unlikely!):

In the end the only way I could find to achieve this functionality was to store the category's current `parent_id` and `nearest_sibling_id` when its `force_to_top` value was set to true.

This way I could move the category to the top of its parent by updating its `lft` and `rgt` values, and then when the `force_to_top` was removed, I could check the `nearest_sibling_id` still existed, and that it was still within the original `parent_id`. If so, move the category back next to its `nearest_sibling_id`; if not, just move the category to the bottom of its original `parent_id` as we can't determine where it really was originally positioned as our `nearest_sibling_id` value is out of date.